# Regular Expression doesn't cover all cases

Tags: java, regex

I have the following problems to solve:

> Write a Java program that accepts a string as an input. Use the
>   following method:
>
> ```
> public static String notReplace(String str)
> ```
>
> This method must returns a string where every appearance of the word
>   "is" has been replaced with "is not". The string "is" should not be
>   immediately preceeded or followed by a letter.
>
> for example: "is test" should be changed to "is not test".
>
> "this is right" should be changed to "this is not right".

Here is the regex that I've used in my code:

```
"(\\W)*(is)(\\W)*|^(is)(?!\\w)"
```

If I enter "is", it changes to "is not" as expected.
However, it doesn't cover "this is right". It gives me "th is not  is not right".

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
String repl = str.replaceAll("(?<![a-zA-Z])is(?![a-zA-Z])", "is not");
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jK0aV8/2)

Comment: Are the lookahead/lookbehind assertions actually needed? seems like "\\bis\\b" would be enough, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: If the string "is" is immediately preceded/followed by a letter, then it won't be a word boundary, however.